# C++ deleting function pointer before end of scope

Tags: c++, scope, function-pointers, destructor

If I have a function:

```
std::string returnString() {
    return "Hello, World!";
}
```

the call:

```
std::string hello = returnString();
std::cout << hello << std::endl;
```

produces `Hello, World!`.

However, if I try:

```
const char* hello = returnString().c_str();
```

and try to print with:

```
for (const char* p = hello; *p; ++p ) {
    std::cout << *p;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

It gives me an error saying `Invalid read of size 1`, which means  p is `NULL`.

What is causing this behaviour?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: How is that question about OpenGL?

Comment: "_the difference between const char* vertSource = read_file(m_FragPath);_" the difference is that it is not valid?

Comment: Edited the tags and question, but it was meant to be `const char* vertSource = read_file(m_FragPath).c_str();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Note: I'm glossing over some details here.  Look up Return Value Optimization and Copy Elision if you want to know the exceptions to the rules I'm mentioning here.  The don't change the behavior I describe in this answer though).

When you return an object from a function, the returned object is destroyed at the end of the line in which the function was called.  This is *always* the case.  Nomrally, you'll copy or move that object into another object in the local scope as in your last snippet:

```
std::string hello = returnString();
```

In this line, `returnString` returns one `std::string` object, `hello` is move-constructed from the returned object, and then the original object is destroyed.

If you consider a slightly different line, that's when problems arise:

```
const char* hello = returnString().c_str();
```

In this case, `returnString` returns a `std::string` object, you save a pointer to the `char` array owned by that `std::string` object, then the original `std::string` object is destroyed, taking the array of `char`s you have a pointer to with it.

---

`std::string` retains ownership of the array of `char`s pointed to by the pointer returned by `c_str`.  The `std::string` deletes the array it owns when it goes out of scope, which means that the lifetime of the array pointed is tied to the lifetime of the `std::string` object.

You can think of `std::string` as looking something like this:

```
class string
{
public:
    string(const char* str)
        : ptr_(new char[strlen(str) + 1])
    {
        strcpy(ptr_, str);
    }

    ~string()
    {
        delete[] ptr_;
    }

    const char* c_str()
    {
        return ptr_;
    }

    // other members

private:
    const char* ptr_;
};
```

The real `std::string` is a bit more complicated, but the basic idea is the same.  When the `std::string` object is constructed, it allocates an array of `char`s to hold the string data, and when the `std::string` object is destroyed it deletes that array.

The `c_str` method just returns a pointer to the `std::string`'s internal `char` array.  Just because you have a pointer to that array doesn't mean that it won't be deleted when the `std::string` object dies, it just means you have a pointer to some memory that you no longer own.

Comment: Good explanation, except that to C++, a newline is just like any other whitespace.  The preprocessor cares about lines, nothing else does.  In particular, talking about lines could cause misunderstanding of code like `for (const char* p = f().c_str(); *p, ++p ) { ... }`  All usages of `p` are in the same line as the temporary `std::string`, even part of the same `for` statement.  And it's still UB due to a lifetime problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt While it would be more correct to use "statement" instead of "line", I feel complicating the answer with an explanation "of what is a statement?" would just distract from the core concept I'm trying to explain.  Thus I chose to use the colloquial "line" to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. So to simplify, if the function bypassed `std::string` completely and returned a C string, the reference wouldn't get deleted?

Comment: @jackw11111: If it returned a C string, it wouldn't get automatically freed -- ever.  Not a problem if the C string has static storage duration, like a string literal.  If it's dynamic data, from a file perhaps, you would have a memory leak.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: I already gave an example showing why "statement" wouldn't be more correct.

Comment: @jackw11111 That depends how the array of `char`s was created.  A string literal lives for the lifetime of the program.  A locally-scoped array will go out of scope when the function returns, and require some extra mechanism to copy it.  A dynamically-allocated array will live until you explicitly `delete[]` it.

Comment: @MilesBudnek @BenVoigt Okay. So the array gets deleted due to the `delete ptr_` or equivalent call in the destructor of `std::string` that occurs when the object is destroyed. This doesn't occur in the `string hello = returnString()` line because it copies the object before deletion. Thanks again.

Comment: @jackw11111 That's the idea, yes.  In some cases the object returned from `returnString` may transfer ownership of the same array of `char`s to `hello` (or they may not exist as distinct objects at all, see my note about copy elision), but that is the behavior you will observe.  If you do not initialize a `std::string` object from the return value of `returnString`, then the array of `char`s returned by `c_str` will cease to exist at the next `;`.